# Different output when elevations data hosted on Tomcat and Node server

Tags: node.js, openlayers-3, cesiumjs

When i write below code and host .terrain files on Tomcat, i can correctly see elevations of an area:

```
var terrainProvider = new Cesium.CesiumTerrainProvider({      
  url: 'http://localhost:8080/terrain/terrain_52_06'
});
this.scene.terrainProvider = terrainProvider;
```

But, when i write below code and host .terrain files on nodejs server, i can see elevations of the area, but in addition to that i can see elevated spikes all over map on the globe also:

```
var terrainProvider = new Cesium.CesiumTerrainProvider({      
  url: 'http://localhost:3005/terrain/terrain_52_06'
});
this.scene.terrainProvider = terrainProvider;
```

Basically, my app runs on node server at: http://localhost:3005.
So, in the Tomcat case, i enable CORS and then it works, whereas in Node server i dont need CORS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mush specify headers "Content-Type" and "Content-Encoding" for .terrain files. For example, if you are using express, it will be something like this:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With');
    if (path.extname(req.url) === '.terrain') {
        res.header('Content-Type', 'application/octet-stream');
        res.header('Content-Encoding', 'gzip');     
    }
    next();  
}
```

I hope it will help.